# Get all sub directories that only contain files

Tags: c#, .net

I have a path and I want to list the subdirectories under it, where each subdirectory doesn't contain any other directory. (Only those subdirectories which don't contain folders, but only files.)

Any smart way to do so?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the bit in brackets at all - could you try rewriting it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is my understanding that you want to list the subdirectories below a given path that contain only files.

---

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetSubdirectoriesContainingOnlyFiles(string path)
{
  return from subdirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
         where Directory.GetDirectories(subdirectory).Length == 0
        select subdirectory;
}
```

Comment: I know this question is 3 years old, but can you explain how this works?  As this is the exact answer I'm looking for.  I just want to make sure I understand the code.

Comment: For a directory with no subdirectories, `Directory.GetDirectories(subdirectory)` will return an empty `string[]`, which will have a `Length` of `0`. Hence, we pick only directories who match that criterion to grab the directories containing only files (possibly no files as well, though).

Comment: Great LINQ usage! Maybe you could use `where !Directory.GetDirectories(subdirectory).Any()` instead of `where Directory.GetDirectories(subdirectory).Length == 0` to make the meaning a little clearer :)

Answer (score 16):

[DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(<path to dir>);
DirectoryInfo[] subdirs = dInfo.GetDirectories();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Directory.GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories.aspx) method.

However I'm not sure I understood your question correctly... could you clarify ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on Havard's answer, but a little shorter (and maybe slightly easier to read because it uses `!Subdirs.Any()` instead of `Subdirs.Length == 0`):

```
static IEnumerable<string> GetSubdirectoriesContainingOnlyFiles(string path)
{
   return Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
          .Where( subdir => !Directory.GetDirectories(subdir).Any() );
}
```

Also note, that this requires `using System.Linq;` to work, since it uses the LINQ query language. (And of course `using System.IO;` for the `Directory` class :))