# How do I extract each folder name from a path?

Tags: c#, .net

How do I extract each folder name from a path if I don't know how many folders there are in the path and I don't know the folder names?

Comment: Writing some code in the first place would help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736462/c-sharp-getting-the-folder-name-from-a-path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407986/get-all-sub-directories-from-a-given-path

Comment: Do you want it to be recursivem or just in that path - As in, do you want subfolders too?

Answer (score 7):

Split the string by using seprator:

```
var dirs[] = completePath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
```

after iterate over each subfolder and construct possible subpaths

```
var composition = string.Empty;
var directoryPathList = new List<string>();
foreach(var s in dirs) {
     composition += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + s; 
     directoryPathList.Add(composition);         
}
```

Comment: +1 for using DirectorySeparatorChar

Answer (score 5):

You can just use `String.Split`:

```
string fileName = @"C:\foo\bar\baz.txt";
string directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName); // "C:\foo\bar"
string allDirectoryNames = directory.Split('\\'); // ["C:", "foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: I'd use `System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` instead of `'\\'`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this:

```
String path = @"\\MyNetwork\Test\my progs\MySource.cpp";

String[] names = Path.GetDirectoryName(path).Split(new Char[] {
    Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// names contains ["MyNetwork", "Test", "my progs"]
```